# Java EE Web Project with Maven : 404 not found no error message

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets, jakarta-ee

i have a huge problem when i launch a web app with maven on eclipse Neon.2 4.6.2 (for Java EE IDE).

When i use the main servlet, nothing happen other than a http 404 on my computer, without any error message. In console, eclipse return this error :

> GRAVE: Servlet [AccueilServlet] in web application [/GestionTrajet]
>   threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   presentation.AccueilServlet   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

In facts, i've tried several possibilites and the last one was to uninstall everything (eclipse / jdk / jre / library .. etc) and redo everything to have a clean version, but the problem didn't change, same error.

On the computer of my friend, everything is fine, he can launch the servlet (named AccueillServlet.java), and he had no 404 error. We are working with Git so i have the exact same version of the project.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>accueil.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AccueilServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>presentation.AccueilServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AccueilServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/accueil</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!--    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ListeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>presentation.ListeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ListeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/liste</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->


</web-app>
```

**Accueil.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Default title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/template.css" />
</head>
<style></style>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="DivNavBar">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="navbar-header">             
                <img src="http://www.sodifrance.fr/sites/default/files/images/logos/logo-sodifrance-menu-business.png" alt="Sodifrance logo" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="DivFooter">               
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </nav>

    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2 align="center">Programme collaboratif</h2>
        <h3>Merci de vous identifier</h3>

        <form  method="post">
        Identifiant
        <input id="login" type="text" name="login" /><br />
        Mot-de-Passe
        <input id="pwd" type="text" name="pwd" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Se Connecter" />
        <br /><br />
        </form>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

    <footer class="col-sm-12"> </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

**AccueilServlet.java**

```
package presentation;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import entite.Connexion;
import metier.ConnexionApplicationImpl;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Accueil
 */
//@WebServlet("/accueil")
public class AccueilServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AccueilServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doWork(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doWork(request, response);
    }

    private void doWork(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ModelBean bean = new ModelBean("", "");
        String page ="/accueil.jsp";
        System.out.println("passage servlet accueil");

        // traitement des entrÃ©es
        if (request.getParameter("login") != null && request.getParameter("pwd") != null) {
            System.out.println("passage if login pwd différent null");
            Connexion connex = ConnexionApplicationImpl.getInstance().returnConnexion(request.getParameter("login"), request.getParameter("pwd"));

            if (connex.getLogin().equals("erreur") && connex.getNom().equals("erreur") && connex.getPwd().equals("erreur") && connex.getPrenom().equals("erreur")) {
                System.out.println("passage if erreur");
                request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
            } else {
                System.out.println("passage else login pwd OK");
                bean = new ModelBean(request.getParameter("login"),request.getParameter("pwd"));
                page = "liste";
                System.out.println(page);
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/GestionTrajet/liste");
                request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
            }

            // a = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("A"));
            // b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("B"));
            // c = a + b;
            // bean = new ModelBean(a.toString(), b.toString(), c.toString());

        }

        // passage Ã  la vue
        System.out.println(page);
        request.setAttribute("bean", bean);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(page).forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**
UPDATE : 23/12/2016

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sodifrance</groupId>
    <artifactId>GestionTrajet</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GestionTrajet Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependendance MongoDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependendance JEE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- standard.jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependendance JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bug JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependendance Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependendance fonctionnement tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <finalName>GestionTrajet</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Directory**

[My project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayuQx.png)

I am new in Java EE techno, but from my pov, it's look like Maven is doing something wrong. I've tried with the exact same version of eclipse from my friend and it didn't work at all, doing the same error over again.

If it's a problem inside the source code, if you could just give me few indications that can help me to find the main problem. I am not sur, but i think that the problem come from eclipse, may be library or maven, but not from the code.

(Thanks in advance for help, and sorry for english mistakes)

**EDIT 23/12/2016**

First of all, thanks for your answer, i corrected the dependencies problems, i did not know that could be a problems :)

I found an other error when i used "Debug As : Maven Test" on my project and it's look like it can't compile because he can't find the compiler (see the error below)

[Message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNzU5.png)

I tried to edit eclipse.ini and give him the jdk location (and i might do something wrong, i just tried something), but it return the same error.

Comment: I can give a version of the complet project, it may have some code error, but we should be able t at least start the webapp main servlet

Comment: It's interesting that you are blaming Maven for doing something wrong but you get an error during runtime which shows that you are doing something wrong (missing web.xml etc.) Apart from having duplicated dependencies in your pom file (javax.servlet: 3.0.1 / 2.5 ?) etc. Furthermore have you checked to build your project simply on command line via `mvn clean package` and taken the built war file and deploy it to JEE container...and it looks like the problem is located at starting...

Comment: even with duplicated dependencies, it didn't explaian why it still work for my friend and not me (we are working with a git with the exact the version of the project)

Comment: There is may be some error in the core code, but i should be able to see the main page "Accueil" like him no ?

Comment: For starters, remove the redundant servlet dependencies from pom.xml, as khmarbaise sais - and note that it is specified **3 times!** As per the web.xml, you should keep only one javax.servlet-api:3.0.1 version. Do a quick check for other duplicates (or triplicates) too. Then change the scope of the JEE dependencies to provided. Otherwise the JARs will end up in the runtime classpath and you will most certainly have classloading errors. If on Tomcat/Jetty, CDI is not provided, if on a full application server, CDI is provided too. Good luck!

Comment: What is the server you are deploying the application on?

Comment: It is a Tomcat 7.0